# Transparent Overlay Image Triggered From Underlaid Image On Hover

Tags: css, image, hover, overlay

I have a number of images which expand when hovered, they all have an expand icon which when hovered directly over disappears using opacity:0;.
Ideally I'm attempting to get this icon to disappear when hovering anywhere in the image so as not to show up when the image is fully expanded.
A light and simple solution would be ideal, thanks in advance of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With js you can try this:

```
$(".step1 img").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".image-overlay").fadeOut(400);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find(".image-overlay").fadeOut(400);
    }
);
```

Or instead fadeOut/fadeIn you can usa toggleClass, or addClass

With css you can try this

```
.step1:hover .image-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, used the css method and works perfectly, I tried various configurations on the same theme but would've have got that.